# How to find a special lower bound of binomial coefficient via Stirling Formula?

Tags: combinatorics, numerical-methods

I have following task:

Let $d,m \in \mathbb{N} $ and we define $\tau \geq e^{\pi - 1}$.
Then it follows $ \binom{m + d}{m} \geq (\frac{m}{\tau d})^d$.

In a paper the inequality  is mentioned without any further explaination except we use Stirling's formula.

Neither I haven't found any formula to explain this nor I can easily change Stirling's formula to fit.

Do you have any proposal?

Comment: Really $d,m\in\Bbb R$ and not $\in \Bbb N$?

Comment: $ d \in \mathbb{N} $ but $ m \in  \mathbb{R} $. If you have an idea with $ \in  \mathbb{N} $ you are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\tau\ge e^{\pi-1}\approx 8.5\gg 1$, 
$${m+d\choose m}={m+d\choose d}=\frac{(m+d)(m+d-1)\cdots (m+1)}{d(d-1)\cdots 1}>\frac{m\cdot m\cdots m}{d\cdot d\cdots d} =\left(\frac md\right)^d>\left(\frac m{\tau d}\right)^d$$

Comment: Sometimes it is too easy...